# Jquery: look for height of child div and change height of parent div

Tags: jquery

I have a div structure which allows to expand content if there is some limit reached (content expand is fired by button click).

Currently this limit depends of how much div blocks child div contains, but there can be more than one text row in each `somecontent` div, so it's not too good. What I want is to look for height of child div and if it reached limit of parent div `height` - change parent div `height` to `100%`;

Please take a look at HTML structure:

```
<div class="parentdiv">
   <div class="childdiv">
      <div class="somecontent">
      </div>
      <div class="somecontent">
      </div>
      <div class="somecontent">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS for `parentdiv`:

```
.parentdiv {
   width: 100%;
   height: 450px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Is it possible to reach this condition with Jquery? If it's not - maybe there is some way to look how much text rows div blocks contain?

Comment: Sorry, your question is a bit unclear - it sounds like you want to grow your parent div to be as tall as the content inside it, why not use `min-height:450px` instead of height

Comment: Well it's just because of functionality. It needs to show full content only after button is pressed, not always. That's why I need to look for some conditions to know when I can show expand button. If limit was not reached - text will be just shown "as it is". If it reached the limit - there will be text fade and button "expand" will be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following jQuery:

```
var parent = $('.parentdiv'),
    child = parent.children('.childdiv');

if (child.height() > parent.height()) {
    parent.height(child.height());
    // can also use parent.height('auto');
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8GK/2/)